# Polkadot Raw data signing is not supported for hardware wallets Ledger

Tags: polkadot, ledger

Raw data signing is not supported for hardware wallets Ledger.
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/signing

how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you already found the best place to post this issue: https://github.com/Zondax/ledger-polkadot/issues/175. Hopefully the Zondax team will get back to you.